# iOS, how to add Arabic in "Metadata and Uploads"

Tags: ios, metadata, arabic

I want to add Arabic language in my app's "Metadata and Uploads" besides default English language. I clicked "English (Default)" drop-down list, but could not find Arabic there. Is it because it's a right-to-left language?

I've added Arabic localizable.strings in my app, now need this language added in this itunesconnect page, so that my app can be listed in Arabic.

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple is still not supporting Arabic as a localized language in iTunes Connect. Although localized support for Arabic is available for iOS apps, viewing App Store metadata pages in Arabic is still not supported as of today.

Your best bet is to include the Arabic translation below the English details for now.